# Cumsum of fixed amount of elements without loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cumsum

I have Python which counts cumsum of 14 elements in column, starting from different elements and writes this sum in other column. Does anyone knows the way how to do it without loops?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame({"A": [i for i in range(25)]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"B": [np.nan for i in range(25)]})
for i in range(4, len(b)):
    cumsum = 0
    for k in range(i - 4, i):
        cumsum += a.A[k]
    b.B[k] = cumsum
pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```

Comment: Did you Google [`pandas cumsum`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+cumsum)?

Comment: There is a cumsum function in pandas: DataFrame.cumsum(axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, skipna=True, **kwargs)

Comment: yes, as I found out it counts cumsum through the whole column, but I need cumsum of 5 past element from 15, for example and it should write into "B": 65(11+12+13+14+15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you are looking for [rolling(4)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) + `sum()`:

```
In [83]: a['new'] = a.A.rolling(4).sum()

In [84]: a
Out[84]:
     A   new
0    0   NaN
1    1   NaN
2    2   NaN
3    3   6.0
4    4  10.0
5    5  14.0
6    6  18.0
7    7  22.0
8    8  26.0
9    9  30.0
10  10  34.0
11  11  38.0
12  12  42.0
13  13  46.0
14  14  50.0
15  15  54.0
16  16  58.0
17  17  62.0
18  18  66.0
19  19  70.0
20  20  74.0
21  21  78.0
22  22  82.0
23  23  86.0
24  24  90.0
```

check:

```
In [86]: pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
Out[86]:
     A   new     B
0    0   NaN   NaN
1    1   NaN   NaN
2    2   NaN   NaN
3    3   6.0   6.0
4    4  10.0  10.0
5    5  14.0  14.0
6    6  18.0  18.0
7    7  22.0  22.0
8    8  26.0  26.0
9    9  30.0  30.0
10  10  34.0  34.0
11  11  38.0  38.0
12  12  42.0  42.0
13  13  46.0  46.0
14  14  50.0  50.0
15  15  54.0  54.0
16  16  58.0  58.0
17  17  62.0  62.0
18  18  66.0  66.0
19  19  70.0  70.0
20  20  74.0  74.0
21  21  78.0  78.0
22  22  82.0  82.0
23  23  86.0  86.0
24  24  90.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!